# Как узнать активный элемент dropDownList в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно чтобы в зависимости от выбранного элемента в dropDownList был вывод следующего поля - если string, то выводим текстового поля, если image - fileInput
Вот такой код листа

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([
    'string' => 'string',
    'image' => 'image',
]);
```

Пытался так делать, но ни работает

```
if($model->type = 'image')
{
    echo $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput();
}
else
{
   echo $form->field($model, 'value')->textInput();
}
```

Нужно как-то считывать активный элемент и в if() записывать ?

Answer (score 1):

тебе нужна повесить js обработчик на твой `<select>` и в зависимости от выбраного типа показывать/разблокировать или скрывать/блокировать нужные поля.

Если у тебя всего 2 поля тогда можно организовать переключатьли типов с помощью `input:radio`:

```
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
$('#type_switcher input:radio').on('click', function() {
    $('#type_switcher').find('input:not(:radio)').each(function(){
        this.disabled = true;
    });
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input:not(:radio)').each(function(){
        this.disabled = false;
    });
});
JS
);
```

Выводим поля для формы

```
<div id="type_switcher" class="form-group" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;">
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')
    ->fileInput([
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'disabled' => $model->type != $model::TYPE_FILE
    ])
    ->label(
        Html::activeRadio($model, 'type', [
            'value' => $model::TYPE_FILE,
            'label' => $model->getAttributeLabel('file'),
            'id' => Html::getInputId($model, 'type') . '_' . $model::TYPE_FILE,
        ])
    ) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'value')
    ->textInput([
        'maxlength' => true,
        'disabled' => $model->type != $model::TYPE_VALUE
    ])
    ->label(
        Html::activeRadio($model, 'type', [
            'value' => $model::TYPE_VALUE,
            'label' => $model->getAttributeLabel('value'),
            'id' => Html::getInputId($model, 'type') . '_' . $model::TYPE_VALUE,
            'uncheck' => null, // !!!
        ])
    ) ?>
</div>
```